# It is wise to create a variable to avoid using several times a count?

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop

Many times I'm in front of a code like that:

```
var maybe = 'some random linq query'
int maybeCount = maybe.Count();
List<KeyValuePair<int, Customer>> lst2scan = maybe.Take(8).ToList();
for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
{
    if (k + 1 <= maybeCount) custlst[k].Customer = lst2scan[k].Value;
    else custlst[k].Customer = new Customer();
}
```

Each time I have a code like this. I ask me, must I create a variable to avoid the for-each calculate the `Count()` ?. Maybe for only 1 `Count()` in the loop it's useless.

1. Somebody have an advice with the "right way" to code that in a loop. Do you do in case per case or ?
2. In this case, is my `maybeCount` variable useless ?
3. Do you know if the `Count()` count each time or he just return the content of a count variable.

Thanks for any advice to improve my knowledge.

Comment: By all means create a variable, but please don't call it `cnt`. That just reads like a highly offensive insult word. Call the variable `maybeCount` so it's obvious what value it holds.

Comment: Honestly, I'd drop `cnt` completely and swap `if (k + 1 <= cnt)` for `if (k + 1 <= lst2scan.Count)`.

Comment: @David, okay my english is not enough deep to understand that. I just search yet in an urban dictionnary what that mean... So sorry, nice to know that. And btw I just named `cnt` for SO, in my original code I call it `tot`. I rename it now so we are clear. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the count is guarranteed to not change then yes this will stop the need to calculate the count multiple times, this can become more important when the Count is resolved from method that can take some time to execute.

If the count does change then this can result in erroneous results being generated.

In answer to your questions.

1. The way you have done it looks pretty reasonable
2. As mentioned, your `cnt` variable means that you won't have to repeat your linq query on each iteration.
3. The count will be determined each time you call it, it has no memory for what the count is

Note: It is important to note that I am talking about the [`Enumerable.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method. The [`List<T>.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a property that can just return a value

Comment: Yes I was talking about a not changing Count. And yes it's important, my question was about the `List<T>.Count` but I have the same for the `Enumerable.Count`, more generally the best way to code a for loop. You say `List<T>.Count` is a property, ok but why must we use this syntax: `.Count()`. I read the difference between `List<T>Count' and `Enumerable.Count` but my logic say me when we have brackets, it's not a property. No ?

Comment: @AlfredWallace - The code you have shown is using `Enumerable.Count` which is a linq query on some data. The list count doesn't need the `()` as it is a property. Your logic is correct, without the brackets it is a property. If you were to use the List<T>.Count then there is no performance gained by saving the `List<T>`'s count to a variable. Be wary though that developers can insert other code into a property's getter/setter that can make it do things - and for the most part I would discourage you from doing this)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends ;)

1. I wouldn't use a loop. I would do something like this:

-

```
var maybe = 'some random linq query'
// if necessary clear list
custlst.Clear();
custlst.AddRange(maybe.Take(8).Select(p => p.Value));
custlst.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 8 - custlst.Count).Select(i => new Customer()));
```

-

2. In this case, yes.
3. It depends if the underlying type is a List (a Collection, in fact) or a simple enumerable. The implementation of Count will look for a precomputed Count value and use it. So, if you're cycling a list, the variable is almost useless (still a little faster, but I don't think it's relevant by any means), if you're cycling a Linq query, a variable is recommended, because Count is going to cycle the entire enumeration.

Just my 2c.

Edit: for reference, you can find the source for .Count() at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs (around line 1489); as you see, it checks for ICollection, and uses the precomputed Count property.